# How do I open local files without an extension as html files?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am using the csvtotable python package to create a self-contained html table from a csv (https://github.com/vividvilla/csvtotable). The table has links to html files in a network folder that open correctly

My problem is that I would also like to be able to open files on the network that are in effect html files but do not have the html extension (renaming the files or copying and renaming isn't an option). These only appear as plaintext when opened. Is there a way for me to tell the browser to open these files as if they were html files, even though the don't have the extension?

Ideally, the solution would be a self-contained html file where I don't have to host other files on the network to work.

Thank you

Comment: If you control the webserver that hosts the files you can have it send a content type header.